github action job needs dependencies while same job don't need in GitLab
recently i migrated the repo from GitLab to GitHub i have runner in GitLab as well as in GitHub however the same job running in github says it requires dependencies like maven java etc. however it didn't had any such issue while running in GitLab what could be the reason for this
gitlab ci
---
before_script:
  - export M2_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/maven3
  - export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
  - export PATH=$M2:$PATH
  - export JENKINS_HOME=/var/jenkins_home
  - export JAVA_HOME=${JENKINS_HOME}/jdk17
  - export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  - export MAVEN_CLI_OPTS="--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true"

# This will only validate and compile stuff
validate:
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test-compile -P lib-snapshot'
  image: jenkins-worker node image(actually it is jenkins image url)

# Validate merge requests
verify:
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS verify -P lib-snapshot'
    - cat cart/target/site/jacoco/index.html | grep -o 'Total[^%]*%'
  coverage: '/Total.*?([0-9]{1,3})%/'
  except:
    - master
  image: jenkins-worker node image(actually it is jenkins image url)

Github workflow
name: e
on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
concurrency:
  group: "${{ github.ref }}"
  cancel-in-progress: true
jobs:
  validate:
    runs-on: github runner image name (org name)
    container:
      image:  jenkins-worker node image(actually it is jenkins image url)
    timeout-minutes: 60
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.0
      with:
        fetch-depth: 20
        lfs: true
    - run: export M2_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/maven3
    - run: export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
    - run: export PATH=$M2:$PATH
    - run: export JENKINS_HOME=/var/jenkins_home
    - run: export JAVA_HOME=${JENKINS_HOME}/jdk17
    - run: export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
    - run: export MAVEN_CLI_OPTS="--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true"
    - run: mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test-compile -P lib-snapshot
  verify:
    needs: validate
    runs-on: github runner image name (org name)
    container:
      image:  jenkins-worker node image(actually it is jenkins image url)
    if: !(github.ref == 'refs/heads/master')
    timeout-minutes: 60
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.0
      with:
        fetch-depth: 20
        lfs: true
    - run: export M2_HOME=/var/jenkins_home/maven3
    - run: export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
    - run: export PATH=$M2:$PATH
    - run: export JENKINS_HOME=/var/jenkins_home
    - run: export JAVA_HOME=${JENKINS_HOME}/jdk17
    - run: export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
    - run: export MAVEN_CLI_OPTS="--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true"
    - run: mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS verify -P lib-snapshot
    - run: cat cart/target/site/jacoco/index.html | grep -o 'Total[^%]*%'

I am getting the following error:
__e/node20/bin/node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /__e/node20/bin/node)
17/__e/node20/bin/node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /__e/node20/bin/node)
18/__e/node20/bin/node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /__e/node20/bin/node)
19/__e/node20/bin/node: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /__e/node20/bin/node)
20/__e/node20/bin/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /__e/node20/bin/node)
21/__e/node20/bin/node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /__e/node20/bin/node)  

I tried steps to install GLIB maven etc. but it didn't download   in GitHub action but it failed to download.

both workflows run on a container, GitLab container comes with popular dependencies preinstalled, while GitHub container doesn't. You should add a few lines of code and install necessary dependencies.

Notice that exporting variables like you do in the Actions workflow doesn't work. You have to use an environment file, $GITHUB_ENV, for that.
